# Filtering nested dictionary based on filter condition passed as dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Below is the nested dictionary containing netflow data.
I need to filter out the packets that are passing the filter_criteria passed as a dictionary
for eg:{'dstport': '443'} (all packets and flows where dstport = 443) or
multiple filters like {'srcaddr':'192.168.10.10','dstport': '443'} (all packets and flows where srcaddr = 192.168.10.10 and dstport = 443)

```
{
    "packet26": {
        "cflow.version": "9",
        "cflow.cflow.version": "9",
        "cflow.count": "1",
        "cflow.cflow.count": "1",
        "cflow.sysuptime": "7.517000000",
        "cflow.cflow.sysuptime": "7.517000000",
        "cflow.timestamp": "Jan  4, 2024 02:31:42.000000000 PST",
        "cflow.cflow.timestamp": "Jan  4, 2024 02:31:42.000000000 PST",
        "cflow.unix_secs": "1704364302",
        "cflow.cflow.timestamp.cflow.unix_secs": "1704364302",
        "cflow.sequence": "7618",
        "cflow.cflow.sequence": "7618",
        "cflow.source_id": "16842752",
        "cflow.cflow.source_id": "16842752",
        "FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.flowset_id": "10005",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_id": "10005",
        "cflow.flowset_length": "39",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_length": "39",
        "cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows).cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows).Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.scope_linecard": "257",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.scope_linecard": "257",
        "cflow.scope_template": "15:27",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.scope_template": "15:27",
        "cflow.packetsexp": "0",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.packetsexp": "0",
        "cflow.flowsexp": "142809",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.flowsexp": "142809",
        "cflow.octetsexp": "8854158",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.octetsexp": "8854158",
        "cflow.sampling_algorithm": "1",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.sampling_algorithm": "1",
        "cflow.sampling_interval": "1",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.sampling_interval": "1",
        "cflow.padding": "00:00",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10005] (1 flows).cflow.padding": "00:00",
    },
    "packet27": {
        "cflow.version": "9",
        "cflow.cflow.version": "9",
        "cflow.count": "15",
        "cflow.cflow.count": "15",
        "cflow.sysuptime": "7.517000000",
        "cflow.cflow.sysuptime": "7.517000000",
        "cflow.timestamp": "Jan  4, 2024 02:31:42.000000000 PST",
        "cflow.cflow.timestamp": "Jan  4, 2024 02:31:42.000000000 PST",
        "cflow.unix_secs": "1704364302",
        "cflow.cflow.timestamp.cflow.unix_secs": "1704364302",
        "cflow.sequence": "7619",
        "cflow.cflow.sequence": "7619",
        "cflow.source_id": "16842752",
        "cflow.cflow.source_id": "16842752",
        "FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.flowset_id": "10000",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_id": "10000",
        "cflow.flowset_length": "66",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_length": "68",
        "cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.srcaddr": "192.168.10.10",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddr": "192.168.10.10",
        "cflow.dstaddr": "192.168.10.11",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddr": "192.168.10.11",
        "cflow.srcaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.dstaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.protocol": "6",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.protocol": "6",
        "cflow.srcport": "443",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcport": "38461",
        "cflow.dstport": "46629",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstport": "21473",
        "cflow.ipv6_next_hdr": "0",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.ipv6_next_hdr": "0",
        "cflow.permanent_octets": "2502366",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_octets": "16254",
        "cflow.permanent_packets": "1686",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_packets": "252",
        "cflow.padding": "00:00",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.padding": "00:00",
        "FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_id": "10000",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_length": "68",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddr": "192.168.10.10",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddr": "192.168.10.11",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.protocol": "6",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcport": "21473",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstport": "38461",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.ipv6_next_hdr": "0",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_octets": "759492",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_packets": "546",
        "cflow.FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.padding": "00:00",
        "FlowSet 3 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 3 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 4 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 4 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 5 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 5 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 6 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 6 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 8 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 8 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 9 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 9 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 10 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 10 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 11 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 11 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 12 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 12 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 13 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 13 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "cflow.FlowSet 13 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.padding": "00:00",
        "FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_id": "10000",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_length": "68",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddr": "192.168.10.10",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddr": "192.168.10.11",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.protocol": "6",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcport": "46629",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstport": "443",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.ipv6_next_hdr": "0",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_octets": "56304",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_packets": "858",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.padding": "00:00",
        "FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_id": "10000",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_length": "66",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddr": "192.168.10.10",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddr": "192.168.10.11",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.protocol": "6",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcport": "46629",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstport": "443",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.ipv6_next_hdr": "0",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_octets": "2502366",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_packets": "1686",
    },

    "packet29": {
        "cflow.version": "9",
        "cflow.cflow.version": "9",
        "cflow.count": "20",
        "cflow.cflow.count": "20",
        "cflow.sysuptime": "7.519000000",
        "cflow.cflow.sysuptime": "7.519000000",
        "cflow.timestamp": "Jan  4, 2024 02:31:44.000000000 PST",
        "cflow.cflow.timestamp": "Jan  4, 2024 02:31:44.000000000 PST",
        "cflow.unix_secs": "1704364304",
        "cflow.cflow.timestamp.cflow.unix_secs": "1704364304",
        "cflow.sequence": "7621",
        "cflow.cflow.sequence": "7621",
        "cflow.source_id": "16842752",
        "cflow.cflow.source_id": "16842752",
        "FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.flowset_id": "10000",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_id": "10000",
        "cflow.flowset_length": "66",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_length": "68",
        "cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.srcaddr": "192.168.10.10",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddr": "192.168.10.10",
        "cflow.dstaddr": "192.168.10.11",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddr": "192.168.10.11",
        "cflow.srcaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.dstaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.protocol": "6",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.protocol": "6",
        "cflow.srcport": "143",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcport": "32239",
        "cflow.dstport": "61896",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstport": "21473",
        "cflow.ipv6_next_hdr": "0",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.ipv6_next_hdr": "0",
        "cflow.permanent_octets": "3244122",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_octets": "16254",
        "cflow.permanent_packets": "2208",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_packets": "252",
        "cflow.padding": "00:00",
        "cflow.FlowSet 1 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.padding": "00:00",
        "FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 2 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 3 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 3 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 4 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 4 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 5 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 5 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 6 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 6 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_id": "10000",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_length": "68",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddr": "192.168.10.10",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddr": "192.168.10.11",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.protocol": "6",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcport": "57812",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstport": "443",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.ipv6_next_hdr": "0",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_octets": "30114",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_packets": "444",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.padding": "00:00",
        "FlowSet 8 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 8 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 9 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 9 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
        "FlowSet 10 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 10 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        ...
    },
}
```

Result filtered dictionary should be nested dictionary which matches the filter_criteria

```
Example output:
packet27 FlowSet 14 is matching the filter_criteria {'srcaddr':'192.168.10.10','dstport': '443'}

filtered_dict = {
    "packet27": {
        "FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_id": "10000",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_length": "68",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddr": "192.168.10.10",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddr": "192.168.10.11",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.protocol": "6",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcport": "46629",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstport": "443",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.ipv6_next_hdr": "0",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_octets": "56304",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_packets": "858",
        "cflow.FlowSet 14 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.padding": "00:00",
        "FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_id": "10000",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_length": "66",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddr": "192.168.10.10",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddr": "192.168.10.11",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.protocol": "6",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcport": "46629",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstport": "443",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.ipv6_next_hdr": "0",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_octets": "2502366",
        "cflow.FlowSet 15 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_packets": "1686",
        },
    "packet29": {
        "FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows)": "FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows)",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_id": "10000",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.flowset_length": "68",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.template_frame": "25",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1": "Flow 1",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddr": "192.168.10.10",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddr": "192.168.10.11",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstaddrv6": "::",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.protocol": "6",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.srcport": "57812",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.dstport": "443",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.ipv6_next_hdr": "0",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_octets": "30114",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).Flow 1.cflow.permanent_packets": "444",
        "cflow.FlowSet 7 [id=10000] (1 flows).cflow.padding": "00:00",
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your example code? What did you try?

Comment: `def filter_dict(data, filter_criteria):
    filtered_output = {}
    filtered_dict = {packet_key: filter_keys(packet_data) for packet_key, packet_data in data.items()}
    for packet, details in filtered_dict.items():
        matching_flows = {}
        for flow, values in details.items():
            if all(values.get(key) == value for key, value in filter_criteria.items() if isinstance(values, dict)):
                matching_flows[flow] = values
        if matching_flows:
            filtered_output[packet] = matching_flows
    print(filtered_output)`

Comment: sorry - you should edit the question and add your example code there - multiline code in comments does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! When posting a query, aim to provide a concise and filtered example for better clarity and understanding..

here is what you wanted

```
filter_condition = {'srcaddr':'192.168.10.10','dstport': '443'}
top_counter = {}
filtered_dict = {}
for k,v in my_dict.items():
    conditions = list(filter_condition.keys())
    if k not in top_counter:
        top_counter[k] = {}
    if isinstance(v,dict):
        for c ,cv in filter_condition.items():
            for k1,v1 in v.items():
                if c in k1:
                    if v1 == cv:
                        top_counter[k][c] = v1
                        filtered_dict[k1] = v1
                        break
```

`top_counter` is for your understanding where it for condition correct.

`filter_condition` is your filter condition.